# Upload PDF file to host with WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I upload a PDF file to host via C# so that it is available for download via an adroid app? This is what I have tried, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
static void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = ((FTPsetting)e.Argument).Filename;
    string fullName = ((FTPsetting)e.Argument).FullName;
    string username = ((FTPsetting)e.Argument).Username;
    string password = ((FTPsetting)e.Argument).Password;
    string server = ((FTPsetting)e.Argument).Server;

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", server, fileName)));
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    Stream ftpstream = request.GetRequestStream();
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fullName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    double total = (double)fs.Length;
    int byteread = 0;
    double read = 0;

    do
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            byteread = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
            ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, byteread);
            read += (double)byteread;
            double percontage = read / total * 100;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((int)percontage);
        }
    }
    while (byteread != 0);

    fs.Close();
    ftpstream.Close();
}

static void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Completed" + e.ProgressPercentage + "%");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You will get better answers if you can provide a little more information.  Do you get any errors?  When you step through the code, are all the values set as expected?

Comment: when i set parameter . Nothing changes